# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver Jdbctype4test.Type4test.main(Type4test.java:21)

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc

I have written the following Type4 jdbc connection code in eclipse in which the properties file has been used as a reference and key is assigned to the user,password, driver and url . The funny thing is I find the above error when I try to load the driver from the properties file , however when I directly load the driver by writing it as oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver it finds a connection and prints the connection. It also prints the value referring to the driver key.The problem is only when I try to pass the same thing as reference from the file to load it it throws ClassNotFoundException.Also I have added the ojdbc14 jar file, In order to experiment I also tried ojdbc6. Please let me know what error I am making and why is this error occurring in my Eclipse.

The following code is written

```
public class Type4test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new                 FileInputStream("C:/eclipse/eclipse/workspace/Jdbctype4/src/PropertiesFile/DB.properties"));
    //System.out.println("Username  "+prop.getProperty("user"));
    System.out.println(properties.getProperty("Driver"));
    String propertyDriver = properties.getProperty("Driver");
    Class.forName(propertyDriver);
    //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(properties.getProperty("url"), properties);

    System.out.println(con);
  }
}
```

and the properties file is as follows:-

```
Driver= oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver 
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
user= System
password= root
```

The Exception I found is

```
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver 
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at Jdbctype4test.Type4test.main(Type4test.java:21)
```

Comment: Can you retry after removing the spaces after the `=` in your properties file?

Comment: Right, the **leading** space is not an issue, but it looks like there are also **trailing** spaces in the property file. **They** are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

When I create a `.properties` file and copy&paste the contents from the question into it, I see that some of the lines have **trailing spaces**. They are preserved, while leading spaces will be removed:

```
  ...
  System.out.println("|" + properties.getProperty("Driver") + "|");
  ...
```

Output:

```
|oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver  |
                         ^^
```

Hence you will pass an invalid class name to `Class.forName(propertyDriver);`.

Remove the trailing spaces (and to be sure, also the leading spaces) from the values in the property file, or `trim()` them:

```
...    
String propertyDriver = properties.getProperty("Driver").trim();
....
```

Comment: Yes the problem was the trailing spaces thanks very much I spent lots of time just to solve this error nothing in the code seemed wrong but still it was not working thank you again Andreas Fester